# Selenium iFrame input text

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium to build a test automation where the html is in an iFrame, I was able to find online the lines of code to activate the iFrame, click on a link, and press a button and they are working fine -see following lines:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("06634000000BVL6");
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Loan Details R1")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Edit')]")).Click();
```

I needed to input a text within a textBox in that iFrame, but I couldn't handle the ID or the Class, below is the HTML for the input:

Any thoughts ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you are not able to access  the WebElement in a frame means, you are not in the frame. if you post the html code for Iframe, someone can help you. you need to change the way , how you are switching to frame. IF you want to check weather you are in the frame or not, you just try printing the page source in the console and check weather you text box is present in the code or not.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I'm not sure why the working code is useful. We need more description of what is not working, show the code that isn't working and explain why it's not working or the error message. You reference an IFRAME but you don't show it in your HTML. Add details needed to solve the problem.

Comment: the HTML is too large to have it fit in a text box unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so this will be part answer, part comment.

Based on what you have posted, it looks like you may not be in the correct iframe and we don't have enough of the code from the webpage to tell if there is an additional iframe.

I'd also like to see the code you are using to write text to the field, you may have an issue there.

If you don't and the only issue you have is the selector then try the following. Go get the developer version of firefox. Navigate to your webpage in firefox. Inspect the element where you want to write text to. Once you are in the inspection screen, there is a path bar that can scroll left and right at the bottom of the screen. Check that to confirm that there is only the one iframe you mentioned and that you are in the correct iframe. If that is the issue, you should be good to go, you're code above works for switching between frames. If you are in the right iframe, then try a different method of finding  the element for the text box. I have had the most success with hard to find elements by using the cssselector. To get the cssselector for the element right click on it, navigate to copy and then cssselector. From there your code should look like this (using c#):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("INSERT CSS SELECTOR HERE")).SendKeys("Text");
```